# Erlang:type ref() undefined

Tags: erlang

I am trying to build a piece of Erlang code on Ubuntu 14.04. I got the following error. It seems to be something wrong with the header file. I can not figure it out.

```
type ref() undefined
```

Comment: what piece of code is giving you this error?

Comment: Here is the github link. https://github.com/Lyoko-Jeremie/erlkad

Answer (score 3):

`ref()` is an obsolete type. Change it to `reference()`, and you should get past this error.  (Or add `-type ref() :: reference().` to create an alias in the old name.)

I couldn't find exactly when this type was deprecated, but I get the same error with an R13B04 compiler. (Ubuntu 14.04 comes with R16B03.) So it seems like this piece of code is pretty old, and there might be more issues like this one.

Comment: Thanks. This was very helpful. Now I got two new errors. Can you help me againg? kad_api.erl:185: type ip_address() undefined
kad_api.erl:186: type ip_port() undefined